# Thinkpad E14 RYZEN 5 4500U Kernel Update v5.8.10 Not Working

Tags: kernel

I am facing lots of issues on kernel 5.4 so I decided to update to kernel 5.8.10.

I am getting the following error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okY7f.jpg)

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 with lenovo bios 1.10 , secure boot disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll likely need to update the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in your `/etc/default/grub` file to include `iommu=pt`. If you cannot boot normally, you may need a Live USB to make this work.

1. Edit the Grub boot file as root:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Add the `iommu` flag to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so that you have something like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Run the Grub updater. This is very important. Do not forget:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I have a question about the live USB part. Do I need to use a live usb or can I use my working 5.4 kernel to modify and update the grub file?

Comment: If the 5.4 kernel option is working, that will require fewer steps 

Comment: I modified the grub file and ran grub update. I am still getting the same error when I boot to kernel 5.8.10